# Simultaneous similarity of pair of matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field, and $A,B,A',B'\in M_n(k)$. Do we have any algorithm with polynomial complexity to determine the simultaneous similarity of the pair $(A,B)$ with $(A',B')$?

I found the paper [Friedman - Simultaneous similarity of matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(83)90044-0) which solved the case when $k=\mathbb{C}$. Do we have similar results when $k$ is another field?

Edited: I am assuming that the operations in the field $k$ are constant time. The polynomial complexity refers to the complexity respect to $n$, the size of the matrix.

Comment: One issue with complexity is just computation within $k$. How do you input elements of $k$? How do you measure the size of an element of $k$ (just think of $k=\mathbf{Q}(t)$)?

Comment: This is literally the prototype of an intractably hard, or, as the technical terminology goes, [wild problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_problem).

Comment: By the way, let alone the complexity issue, the question is absolute for $k$ infinite: $(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ is conjugate to $(B_1,\dots,B_n)$ in $M_n(k)$ by an invertible element iff it's conjugate in $M_n(\bar{k})$ by an invertible element. Indeed, define $V(L)$ as the set of solutions $U$ to the linear system $(UA_i=B_iU)_{1\le i\le n}$. Then conjugation over $L$ means that the determinant doesn't vanish on $V(L)$. Since $V(k)$ is Zariski-dense in $V$, this is field-independent (provided $k\subset L$).

Comment: @YCor, I can never keep track of Zariski density results, but I guess there must be some extra hypothesis:  I don't think it's true in *every* smooth, irreducible variety over an infinite field that its rational points are Zariski dense, is it?  (At least, I'm pretty sure that one needs reductivity when dealing with groups.)  If that's correct, then what is the additional hypothesis that makes the rational points of $V$ Zariski dense?

Comment: @LSpice of course not. The point is that $V$ is the set of points of a *linear* system, so Zariski-density is just the Zariski-density of $k^m$ in $L^m$ for $k\subset L$, $k$ infinite.

Answer (score 1):

First find an invertible matrix $C$ conjugating $A$ to $A'$ (I assume you can do that in polynomial time). Consider $E=CBC^{-1}$. It remains to find an invertible $D$ which commutes with $A'$ and conjugates $E$ to $B'$. This is a system of homogeneous linear equations with a constraint that the determinant is not $0$.

Comment: The last step is a special case of polynomial identity testing (the identity being "the determinant equals zero on this linear subspace") which has no determinastic polynomial-time algorithm known in general, though it does have known randomized polynomial algorithm.

Comment: @WillSawin: Right. But the OP did not say what "polynomial time" means in the question. Strictly speaking the first step is undecidable in general if the entries of the matrix are arbitrary complex numbers, for example.

Comment: @dodd I am pretty sure that there is an algorithm with polynomial complexity to determine the first step. Basically, there is a polynomial complexity algorithm to compute the Smith Normal Form of a matrix, and the Smith Normal Form of the matrix $xI-A\in M_n(k[x])$ will produce the invariant factors of $A$ and also an invertible matrix $T$ such that $TAT^{-1}$ is the Rational Canonical Form of $A$.

Comment: @THWang: First you have to define what "polynomial complexity" means in this case. Why Smith and Rational forms when Jordan forms are enough? But I agree that under a suitable definition, step 1 has polynomial complexity. Step 3 is also not so bad because it is easier than  the general polynomial identity testing problem.

Comment: @dodd I am assuming that the operation in the original field $k$ has constant time complexity. I don't want to use the algebraic closure of $k$ since I don't know how to represent those elements nor the complexity of the ring operation. (I am more interested in the case when $k$ is a finite field). My point is that step 1 can be done without using the algebraic closure.

Comment: @THWang: Yes, this is a definition of "complexity" that is needed here. This does not agree with a CS definition  even for the field of rational numbers (although you can argue that you are using algorithms with oracles). To get a Jordan form you do not need algebraic closure, just a finite extension of $k$ which is a quite constructive object.

Comment: There isn't a big need for the first step, since, before that step, the equations are just $UA = BU$, $U A' = B' U$, which are still linear in $U$, as YCor pointed out for the comments.

Comment: @WillSawin: The main thing is step 3. One can take the general solution of the homogeneous system: $x_{i_1}=u_1,...,x_{i_k}=u_k$ and plug it in the determinant. The hope is that the determinant will not become  identically $0$. I do not know if that is equivalent to the general polynomial identity problem.

Comment: @THWang I guess for finite fields the polynomial identity problem is NP-complete, so there is a bigger need for an argument in the special case. I think you should edit your question to specify the finite field case, because, as YCor points out, it behaves very differently from infinite fields.

Comment: @WillSawin: First, you commented a wrong post. Second,  it is not clear whether the p.i.p. for a finite field is NP-complete. I guess you mean the SAT problem, but that is about polynomials over the Boolean algebra.  Third, it is not clear whether the OP problem is equivalent to the p.i.p. It may be much easier.

Comment: @dodd There is a well-known reduction from SAT to the polynomial identity problem, which is easies in the case of $\mathbb F_2$ ( view and as $xy$ and ord as $1- (1-x)(1-y)$). I did not say it was equivalent to the boolean identity problem. The point is that, for many purposes, randomized algorithms are just as good as deterministic, so more work is needed in the finite field case that isn't over infinite fields. I don't know what "You commented a wrong post" means but I don't think I did it.

Comment: @WillSawin: You commented on my answer but addressed it to the question. I did not know that p.i.p. for $\mathbb{F}_2$ is harder than SAT. Thank you! But the problem in the OP may be much easier. It is equivalent to whether the determinant of a matrix of size $n$ with entries linear polynomials is identically zero.

Comment: @dodd I was responding to THWang's comment on your answer - I therefore responded in the same location. I agree that the problem in OP may be easier.

Comment: @dodd: Why don't you merge this answer into your other one? In general, one should post several answers only when they are clearly different. In this case, though, this post seems to be the logical motivation of the other one, therefore this should be pasted (and then deleted) into that one.

Comment: @AlexM; Thank you for your comment. The first answer gives an idea what to do for any field. The second answer answers the question for infinite field..

Answer (score 1):

So let me try to give a definite answer. We have a non-zero system of linear homogeneous equations $\Sigma$ in $n^2$ variables $x_{ij}$ having an infinite set of solutions and the matrix $M=((x_{ij}))$. We want to show that for some values of $x_{i,j}$ satisfying the system the determinant $\det(M)$ is not zero. Consider the general solution of the system and plug it in $M$. Thus we need to check if a matrix $M=((x_{i,j}))$ where each entry is a homogeneous linear polynomial, $\det(M)$ is not identically zero. Let, say, $z_1$, be the LEX smallest variable that appears in a polynomial in $M$. We can assume that it appears in $x_{1,1}$ (switching rows and columns can only  change the sign of the determinant). Then using row and column transformations, we can make all linear polynomials in the first row and the first column of $M$ not depending on $z_1$. Then consider the cofactor matrix $M_{1,1}$. If its entries do not depend on $z$, we are done. If not, then put the entry containing  $z$ in the left top corner of $M_{1,1}$ and continue. As a result we get a matrix $M'$ with linear polynomials containing $z$ on the diagonal and no $z$ appearing anywhere else. The determinant of that matrix is the same as $\det M$ up to sign and is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $z$, so it is not identical zero. That algorithm requires at most $n^8$ operations.

Comment: I see your ideas. So the answer to the infinite field case is yes, and this depends on a fact that a polynomial is zero if and only if it takes value zero at each point, which is only true when $k$ is an infinite field.

Comment: Yes, it is true for infinite fields.

Answer (score -1):

I just read this post and I see -with amusement- that a (knowledgeable?) reader downvoted this post. I believe -on the contrary- that the question is very interesting (although standard).

We give $A,B,A_1,B_1\in M_n(K)$ s.t. $A,A_1$ are similar, $B,B_1$ are similar. We are looking for an invertible $P=[p_{i,j}]\in GL_n(K)$ (if it exists) satisfying the linear system:
$(1)$ $PA-A_1P=0$ and $(2)$ $PB-B_1P=0$.

The vector space of solutions of $(1)$ has the same dimension ($\geq n$ and generically, $n$) as $C(A)$ (the commutant of $A$). The vector space of solutions of $(1,2)$ (the intersection of $2$ subspaces) has generically the dimension $1$ when $P$ exists (that is, the solution is unique -up to a factor-). Of course the dimension $r$ may be $>1$: Let

$A=diag(J_3,J_4,J_5,J_8,I_4+J_4,I_6+J_6),A_1=QAQ^{-1}$,

$B=diag(2I_6+J_6,2I_7+J_7,2I_7+J_7,4I_5+J_5,4I_5+J_5),B_1=QBQ^{-1}$ where $Q$ is random and $J_k$ is the nilpotent Jordan block; then $r=9$.

First step; we solve $(1,2)$; an obvious solution is to calculate the kernel of $I\otimes A^T-A_1\otimes I$ (if we transform a matrix into a vector row by row). The complexity is $O(n^6)$ operations -we will come back to this subject below-

The general solution depends on $r$ parameters that  can be chosen among the $p_{i,j}$.

Case 1. $K$ is infinite; it suffices to randomly choose the considered parameters; the obtained solution is invertible with probability $1$ (if $P$ exists). If, several tests give non-invertible solutions, then there are no solutions. The complexity is in $O(n^3)$.

Case 2. $K$ is finite. Then we need to do more tests, especially if $ K$ is small. Anyway, we can perform $O(n^3)$ tests without increasing the complexity... During my tests, I always found a valid solution very quickly.

$\bullet$ Finally, the true question is "can we solve $(1,2)$ in less than $O(n^6)$ operations?". Our downvoter certainly knows how to answer this question, but I can't. Indeed

1. There are many solvers for the Sylvester equation that work in $O(n^3)$: Bartels-Stewart, Hammarling, Hessenberg-Schur, Krylov subpaces techniques,...
   Yet, these methods work only when the spectra of $A,A_1$ are disjoint and, moreover, the unique solution is done as an approximation.
   Here we need an exact value of $P$ (because of the multiplicities of the eigenvalues ​​of our matrices); on the other hand, we cannot put our matrices in Schur form because we don't know how to calculate the eigenvalues. Of course, we can put $A,B$ in Frobenius form.
2. I am surprised that we do not know a faster method to solve equation $(1)$ because it presents an interesting pattern: $I\otimes A^T-A_1\otimes I$ presents, for $n=40$ and random matrices $A,B,P$, $95$% of zeros located at entries fixed in advance (of course, when $n>40$, the proportion is even greater).

We ask for a specialist in sparse matrices.

EDIT. Answer to  LSpice.

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ We assume that $K$ is infinite. Let $A,B$ be random matrices and $P$ be any invertible matrix; then $r=1$ with probability $1$.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ We may assume that $K$ is algebraically closed (the dimension does not depend on the extension of the field). To be completely rigorous, we can reason using Zariski topology.

With probability $1$, $A,B$ have distinct eigenvalues and have each a basis of eigenvectors, say $(e_i),(f_i)$. Let $E=[e_1,\cdots,e_n],F=[f_1,\cdots,f_n]$. The $P(e_i)'s,P(f_i)'s$ are bases of eigenvectors of $A_1,B_1$ (that have also distinct eigenvalues).

Now, let $Q$ be the general matrix that ensures the simultaneous similarity.
There are non-zero unknowns $(x_i),(y_i)$ s.t. $Q(e_i)=x_ie_i,Q(f_i)=y_if_i$, that is,

$QE=PEdiag(x_i),QF=PFdiag(y_i)$, or $Q=PEdiag(x_i)E^{-1}=PFdiag(y_i)F^{-1}$.

Finally, the condition is $F^{-1}Ediag(x_i)E^{-1}F=diag(y_i)$.

Since $E,F$ are random, $G=F^{-1}E$ too; from $Gdiag(x_i)G^{-1}=diag(y_i)$, we deduce that there is a permutation $\sigma$ s.t. $diag(x_i)=\sigma diag(y_i)\sigma^{-1}$.

Thus $U diag(y_i)=diag(y_i)U$, where $U=G\sigma$ is random. The sole diagonal matrices that commute with $U$ are the scalar matrices.

Consequently, $diag(x_i)=diag(y_i)=uI_n$ and $Q=uP$.

Comment: Why is the solution to a generic equation of the form (1, 2) unique up to a scalar?

Comment: @LSpice , cf. my edit